# Hadoop Mapreduce failing with CreateSymbolicLink

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

Team,

Please be informed that i am running Hadoop mapreduce examples (Version 2.7.1). It is failing with below error.

```
Exit code: 1
Exception message: CreateSymbolicLink error (1314): A required privilege is not held by the client.
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=1: CreateSymbolicLink error (1314): A required privilege is not held by the client.
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:545)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:456)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:722)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:211)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Shell output:         1 file(s) moved.
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1
Failing this attempt. Failing the application.
```

I have searched in google. It seems to be permission issue.

My assumption is Mapreduce is accessing some restricted path/location. Is there any way that i can change the accessing location?

Since i dont have admin permission..

Note : I am running in windows....

Your suggestions are highly appreciated...

Comment: Either run it as a admin or setup hadoop other than c drive

Comment: Unfortunate that i cant both... Since i have only one drive. Ans as said earlier i dont have admin rights...

Is there any scope to identify the path it is trying to access?

Comment: [This Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28958999/hdfs-write-resulting-in-createsymboliclink-error-1314-a-required-privilege) contains the solution.

Comment: @Mahek I am running as an admin, still have same issue