# Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException) for hadoop 3.1.3

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, hadoop3

I am trying to run a mapreduce job but I am getting error for Hadoop-3.1.3

```
hadoop jar WordCount.jar WordcountDemo.WordCount  /mapwork/Mapwork /r_out
```

**Error**

```
2020-04-04 19:59:11,379 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
2020-04-04 19:59:12,499 WARN mapreduce.JobResourceUploader: Hadoop command-line option parsing not performed. Implement the Tool interface and execute your application with ToolRunner to remedy this.
2020-04-04 19:59:12,569 INFO mapreduce.JobResourceUploader: Disabling Erasure Coding for path: /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/tejashri/.staging/job_1586009643433_0007
2020-04-04 19:59:12,727 WARN hdfs.DataStreamer: DataStreamer Exception
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/tejashri/.staging/job_1586009643433_0007/job.jar could only be written to 0 of the 1 minReplication nodes. There are 0 datanode(s) running and 0 node(s) are excluded in this operation.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget4NewBlock(BlockManager.java:2205)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirWriteFileOp.chooseTargetForNewBlock(FSDirWriteFileOp.java:294)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:2731)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:892)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:568)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:527)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1036)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:1000)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:928)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1729)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2916)

        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getRpcResponse(Client.java:1545)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1491)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1388)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:233)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:118)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.addBlock(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:514)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:165)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:157)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeOnce(RetryInvocationHandler.java:95)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:359)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.addBlock(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.addBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:1081)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.locateFollowingBlock(DataStreamer.java:1866)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DataStreamer.java:1668)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.run(DataStreamer.java:716)
2020-04-04 19:59:12,734 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Cleaning up the staging area /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/tejashri/.staging/job_1586009643433_0007
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/tejashri/.staging/job_1586009643433_0007/job.jar could only be written to 0 of the 1 minReplication nodes. There are 0 datanode(s) running and 0 node(s) are excluded in this operation.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget4NewBlock(BlockManager.java:2205)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirWriteFileOp.chooseTargetForNewBlock(FSDirWriteFileOp.java:294)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:2731)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:892)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:568)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:527)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1036)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:1000)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:928)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1729)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2916)

        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getRpcResponse(Client.java:1545)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1491)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1388)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:233)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:118)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.addBlock(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:514)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:165)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:157)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeOnce(RetryInvocationHandler.java:95)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:359)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.addBlock(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.addBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:1081)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.locateFollowingBlock(DataStreamer.java:1866)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DataStreamer.java:1668)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.run(DataStreamer.java:716)
```

**Update** (from comments):

`core-site.xml`

```
<configuration> 
<property> 
<name>fs.default.name</name> 
<value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value> 
</property> 
<property> 
<name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name> 
<value>C:\hadoop\hdfstmp</value> 
</property> 
</configuration>
```

`hdfs-site.xml`

```
<configuration> 
<property> 
<name>dfs.replication</name> 
<value>1</value> 
</property> 
<property> 
<name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name> 
<value>C:\hadoop\data\namenode</value> 
</property> 
<property> 
<name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name> 
<value>C:\hadoop\data\datanode</value> 
</property> 
<property> 
<name>dfs.datanode.failed.volumes.tolerated</name> 
<value>0</value> 
</property> 
</configuration>
```

Output of `jps`:

```
16832 NodeManager 
5556 ResourceManager 
18280 NameNode 
11708 Jps
```

`datanode` error log:

```
2020-04-04 21:42:25,150 WARN common.Storage: Failed to add storage directory [DISK]file:/C:/hadoop/data/datanode
java.io.IOException: Incompatible clusterIDs in C:\hadoop\data\datanode: namenode clusterID = CID-199fd5c5-1f1d-4c44-9e39-80995486695e; datanode clusterID = CID-16d0af22-57e1-4531-a5c8-4bf3eefd351d
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataStorage.doTransition(DataStorage.java:744)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataStorage.loadStorageDirectory(DataStorage.java:294)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataStorage.loadDataStorage(DataStorage.java:407)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataStorage.addStorageLocations(DataStorage.java:387)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataStorage.recoverTransitionRead(DataStorage.java:559)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.initStorage(DataNode.java:1743)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.initBlockPool(DataNode.java:1679)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPOfferService.verifyAndSetNamespaceInfo(BPOfferService.java:390)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPServiceActor.connectToNNAndHandshake(BPServiceActor.java:282)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPServiceActor.run(BPServiceActor.java:822)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2020-04-04 21:42:25,156 ERROR datanode.DataNode: Initialization failed for Block pool <registering> (Datanode Uuid 7578b7ba-c42a-476b-abc2-2088b15b3474) service to localhost/127.0.0.1:9000. Exiting.
java.io.IOException: All specified directories have failed to load.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataStorage.recoverTransitionRead(DataStorage.java:560)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.initStorage(DataNode.java:1743)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.initBlockPool(DataNode.java:1679)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPOfferService.verifyAndSetNamespaceInfo(BPOfferService.java:390)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPServiceActor.connectToNNAndHandshake(BPServiceActor.java:282)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPServiceActor.run(BPServiceActor.java:822)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2020-04-04 21:42:25,158 WARN datanode.DataNode: Ending block pool service for: Block pool <registering> (Datanode Uuid 7578b7ba-c42a-476b-abc2-2088b15b3474) service to localhost/127.0.0.1:9000
2020-04-04 21:42:25,261 INFO datanode.DataNode: Removed Block pool <registering> (Datanode Uuid 7578b7ba-c42a-476b-abc2-2088b15b3474)
2020-04-04 21:42:27,274 WARN datanode.DataNode: Exiting Datanode
```

Comment: Datanode is not running. Could you please update the post with your cluster setup, configuration files and the output of `jps` command.

Comment: cmd:-jps  
 16832 NodeManager
11716
5556 ResourceManager
18280 NameNode
11708 Jps

Comment: As you can see, datanode and secondary namenode daemons aren't running. Could you post the `hdfs-site.xml` and `core-site.xml`

Comment: core-site.xml:
<configuration>
   <property>
 
       <name>fs.default.name</name>
 
       <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
 
   </property>
<property>
 
       <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
       <value>C:\hadoop\hdfstmp</value>
 
   </property>
   
</configuration>

Comment: hdfs-site.xml:
<configuration>
 <property>
  <name>dfs.replication</name>
  <value>1</value>
 </property>
 <property>
  <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
  <value>C:\hadoop\data\namenode</value>
 </property>
 <property>
  <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
  <value>C:\hadoop\data\datanode</value>
 </property>
         <property>
  <name>dfs.datanode.failed.volumes.tolerated</name>
  <value>0</value>
 </property>
</configuration>

Comment: Can you paste the datanode logs in pastebin.com and share!

Comment: https://pastebin.com/5j4STmCJ

Comment: Did you format the namenode later at any point while your cluster was functional? Or to put it in other words, how many times have you formatted the namenode?

Comment: two time i did that because of some error was occuring that time.

Comment: Okay, can you post the log for secondary namenode in pastebin.

Comment: where will i find secondary namenode ?? i am not able to locate the directory

Comment: Logs will be in the same directory as the one where datanode logs were written.

Comment: I still could not locate it
I got a another version file in datanode
namespaceID=1442950721
cTime=1585992740024
blockpoolID=BP-1166567974-192.168.1.6-1585992740024
layoutVersion=-57

Comment: Okay, I will update the answer.

Comment: this complete datanode logs. https://pastebin.com/0vJbN8HS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Mapreduce job fails because it is unable to access HDFS since `There are 0 datanode(s) running and 0 node(s) are excluded in this operation.`

And from the datanode logs, it is understood that the `Datanode` daemon is unable to register itself with the HDFS cluster due to `Incompatible clusterIDs`.

When a namenode is formatted (during installation and setup), a `clusterID` is generated and this clusterID is stored in the `VERSION` file of each daemon when they initialize. This clusterID acts as the identifier for the datanodes, letting them to rejoin the cluster whenever they are stopped and started.

Incompatible clusterIDs among the nodes can happen when the namenode is formatted on an active cluster and the other daemons are not re-initialized.

To get the cluster back in form,

1. Stop the cluster
2. Delete the contents of the following
   directories `C:\hadoop\hdfstmp`, `C:\hadoop\data\namenode`,
   `C:\hadoop\data\datanode`
3. Format the namenode
4. Start the cluster

You have recopy the data required for the Mapreduce job and run the job.

Comment: Thank you, now datanode is working now. 
I also want to run jar file but it always show Input path is not valid. what should i do?

Comment: As I have said, you have to recopy the data to that location.

Comment: in hdfs-site.xml?

Comment: No. The required input files for your wordcount program to the `/mapwork/Mapwork`. You might have done it earlier right, the same thing. You had lost them when the datanode went berserk. Now you have to redo that.

Comment: I tried all the steps again it but showing inputpath is invalid

Comment: Can you show the command you used for uploading the file to hdfs?

Comment: to make new folder in hdfs:   
C:\Users\tejashri>hdfs dfs -mkdir /work

to copy from local system:
hdfs dfs -put C:\Users\tejashri\Desktop\MapWork.txt  /work

to run jar file:

hadoop jar /Desktop/Hadoopproject/WordCount.jar  WordcountDemo.WordCount /MapWork  /out

logs:
https://pastebin.com/9iY5C8zC

Comment: You have copied the input file to `/work`, then your run jar command should also be `hadoop jar /Desktop/Hadoopproject/WordCount.jar WordcountDemo.WordCount /work /out`

Comment: I tried this also but this time got this error:

https://pastebin.com/mNf7YkpD

Comment: The IOException problem is solved. This is a different error. Assuming you are executing these commands from your command prompt, did you start the command prompt with `Run as Administrator`?

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/30143404/7303447. This should solve your error, if it does not, please open a new question with the latest error.

Comment: well , the above link didi not help me to resolve the problem. I will update the new post with new error

Answer (score 0):

I do not have the option to shut down and restart my cluster.  However, running the following command solved the problem without causing any other issue that I could see.

```
hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave
```

See the following:

1. https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsUserGuide.html#DFSAdmin_Command
2. https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsUserGuide.html#Safemode