# Hadoop mapreduce program fail

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have installed Hadoop 3.2.3 stable version. I set all environment variables like JAVA_HOME, HADOOP_HOME, PATH etc.. I configured yarn-site.xml, hdfs-site.xml, core-site.xml, mapred-site.xml.

I uploaded sample files in HDFS. When I am executing the wordcount program in hadoop-mapreduce-examples-3.2.3.jar using below command

**bin\yarn jar share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-3.2.3.jar wordcount /input /output**

However, I got the error like below:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyq7w.png)

Application application_1657253647702_0002 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1657253647702_0002_000002 exited with exitCode: 1
Failing this attempt.Diagnostics: [2022-07-08 12:30:30.730]Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1657253647702_0002_02_000001
Exit code: 1
Exception message: CreateSymbolicLink error (1314): A required privilege is not held by the client.
Shell output: 1 file(s) moved.
"Setting up env variables"
"Setting up job resources"
[2022-07-08 12:30:30.731]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1.
[2022-07-08 12:30:30.731]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1.
For more detailed output, check the application tracking page: http://DESKTOP-P234DBF:8088/cluster/app/application_1657253647702_0002 Then click on links to logs of each attempt.
. Failing the application.

Comment: The core of your issue appears to be "A required privilege is not held by the client" This may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28958999/hdfs-write-resulting-in-createsymboliclink-error-1314-a-required-privilege

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I figured out the solution after did so many research. What I did is, I set the following properties in mapred-site.xml

```
<property>
    <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.env</name>
    <value>HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME</value>
</property>
<property>
   <name>mapreduce.map.env</name>
   <value>HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME</value>
</property>
<property>
   <name>mapreduce.reduce.env</name>
   <value>HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME</value>
```